# How do I add a domain to a app that is already linked to another google apps account?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

My company (Company A) has the domain companya.com that is linked to our apps account. We have a client (Company B) that has the domain companyb.com. Company B already has a apps account that they use for email. They are not very technical and just saying the word DNS or domain scares them. How can we create a App Engine app that uses companyb.com for them but is managed and billed to Company A?

Answer (score 1):

1. B needs to create an appengine project,
2. B needs to add someome from A as owner to this appengine project
3. B needs to change DNS records to point to appengine
4. B needs to change domains alias to point to appengine project
5. A can create the billing for appengine project

A is owner of project, so besides the domain stuff, A can fully mange and pay the appengine app from B

if B have problems with DNS and Domains, B can give A rights to change DNS on there Domain Provider, and B can create an Admin for Domain Alias for A

so you see, best is if B don't have any clue about DNS and Domains, they should also hand over this inside the maintenance contract between A and B